# Console.logging an object shows that the object contains a property that had not yet been assigned

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, vue.js

Not necessarily a problem, but I am not sure why my code works the way that it does and I'm hoping to find some answers here.

The code I have written creates two objects: a user and a company. When a form is submitted the company object is sent to a Mongodb database where it receives an _id. I then assign this _id to the user object to associate the user with a company.

I have console.logs in various places to view what my objects look like as they are passed between different methods. I have discovered that when I console.log the user object BEFORE assigning the companyId to the object, the companyId property is a part of the user object.

```
async handleCreateAccount() {
  let company = Object.assign({}, {
    name: this.companyName,
    url: this.companyUrl
  });
  let user = Object.assign({}, {
    firstName: this.firstName,
    lastName: this.lastName,
    userName: this.userName,
    title: this.title,
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
  });

    console.log('user object no companyId', user)

  this.$store.dispatch('addCompany', company).then((company) => {
    this.companyId = company.id;
    this.handleCreateUser(user)
  })
},
handleCreateUser(user) {

   console.log('user object prior to assigning companyId property', user);

   Object.assign(user, {
     companyId: this.companyId
   })

   console.log('user object with companyId property', user)

}
```

I would expect `console.log('user object no companyId', user)` to display the properties of the user object that I created above this console.log.

I would expect `console.log('user object prior to assigning companyId property', user)` to also display the properties of the user object prior to assigning companyId to the user object.

I would expect `console.log('user object with companyId property', user)` to show the properties of the user object and include a companyId property.

All three console logs display the companyId property with the correct value. Why is this happening?

Comment: I believe that when logging an object in the console you get its current values, not at the time of the log. Try logging JSON.stringify(user)

Comment: `console.log` is asynchronous: it will kick in "whenever is convenient for the JS engine" and if between your invocation and the actual log, the thing that was supposed to get logged changes: too bad. So, if you want to print exactly what you have when you call it, you'll have to take a snapshot of whatever you're logging, e.g. using `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` or `console.log(array.slice())`

Answer (score 2):

Given this code:

```
var x = {};

function y() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        x.foo = 'aaa';
        console.log('after 100ms', x);
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function () {
        x.bar = 'bbb';
        console.log('after 200ms', x);
    }, 200);
    setTimeout(function () {
        x.baz = 'ccc';
        console.log('after 300ms', x);
    }, 300);
    console.log('now', x);
}

y();
```

And the following screencast:

[image]

It may seem that `console.log` captures a snapshot of `x` at the time `console.log` was executed but that is not the case. When you inspect `x`, you actually get `x` as it is now in memory. Hence why you see the property `foo`, `bar` & `baz` on the output labelled with "now".

This is not a bug and is mentioned here:

> Please be warned that if you log objects in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time you call console.log(), but it is the value of the object at the moment you open the console.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

As a "workaround" you can create that snapshot yourself:

```
var x = {};

function snapshot(o) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
}

function y() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        x.foo = 'aaa';
        console.log('after 100ms', snapshot(x));
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function () {
        x.bar = 'bbb';
        console.log('after 200ms', snapshot(x));
    }, 200);
    setTimeout(function () {
        x.baz = 'ccc';
        console.log('after 300ms', snapshot(x));
    }, 300);
    console.log('now', snapshot(x));
}

y();
```

[image]

A lesser known alternative would be to use [`console.table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table):

```
var x = {};


function y() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        x.foo = 'aaa';
        console.table(x);
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function () {
        x.bar = 'bbb';
        console.table(x);
    }, 200);
    setTimeout(function () {
        x.baz = 'ccc';
        console.table(x);
    }, 300);
    console.table(x);
}

y();
```

As you can see each call to `console.table` displays a "visual" snapshot of `x` even though when you inspect the object itself, it would still display the object as it is in memory now:

[image]